# use postman to send a request to a rest API

Tags: node.js, postman

I want to use postman to send a request like GET or POST to a REST API of a nodejs application.

For example to get users of the application, I make a GET and the url must be writed like /v1/users but it returns 404 not found.

Code of file src/v1/users/auth/routes.js :

```
'use strict'

import { Router } from 'express'
import { middleware } from 'express-asyncable'
import x from 'throw-if-missing'
import AuthAttemptLocker from '../../../../request/authAttemptLocker'

const router = Router({ mergeParams: true })

export default function authRouter({
  authController = x`authController`, 
}: {
  authController: Object
}): express$Router<express$Request, express$Response> {
  const authAttemptLocker = new AuthAttemptLocker()

  // Auth management
  router.post(
    '/auth',
    middleware(authAttemptLocker.middleware.bind(authAttemptLocker)),
    middleware(authController.auth.bind(authController))
  )
  router.post(
    '/guest',
    middleware(authController.guest.bind(authController))
  )
  if (process.env.ACTIVATE_GOOGLE_AUTH === '1') {
    router.get(
      '/auth/googlecallback',
      middleware(authController.googleCallback.bind(authController))
    )
  }
  if (process.env.ACTIVATE_REGISTRATION === '1') {
    router.post(
      '/register',
      middleware(authController.register.bind(authController))
    )
    router.get(
      '/activate/:hash',
      middleware(authController.activate.bind(authController))
    )
  }

  return router
}
```

Comment: Post your code it will be easy to answer

Answer (score 1):

are you using the full domain?

```
http://localhost:{port}/v1/users
```

You can also test GET requests by going directly to the url in your browser

Comment: Yes i'm using full domain also

Comment: What is the console output? If you are hitting the correct application the console will output the 404 error